# Get Section text with elisp

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to extract from an org file a top-level headline and the plain text just under it. I'm new to elisp, but i've tried a bunch of things, and haven't made much progress. I'd really appreciate some pointers.

Suppose we've got the file:

```
* Test

Some descriptive text

** TODO Test Org mode
** TODO Keep testing
```

I'd like to include just the top headline and the descriptive text just under it in another file. (Not using #+INCLUDE searches, which for some reason I also can't get to work). So I'm trying to extract just a piece of this buffer's AST.

I'm trying to use `org-map-entries` because it will be able to look through all my agenda files, each of which relates to a different project.

First, does `org-map-entries` just not allow me to access children of headlines? (I think the text description is in a `section` that's a child of the first headline. Right?)

Assuming that's true, I've tried to `org-element-parse-buffer` of the whole buffer when I find a top-level headline. With the whole AST, I think I should be able to get the text just under the top-level headline. But I'm stumped.

Any pointers?

```el
(defun get-headline-with-text ()
    (let ((entry (org-element-at-point)))
        (if (eq 1 (org-element-property :level entry))
            (let ((hdl (nth 2 (org-element-parse-buffer))))
                 (list (org-element-property :raw-value hdl) 
                       (org-element-property :value (car (org-element-contents hdl))))
            )
            nil)
    )
)

(org-map-entries '(get-headline-with-text) t nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, does org-map-entries just not allow me to access children of headlines? (I think the text description is in a section that's a child of the first headline. Right?)

`org-map-entries` by default walks through the full data. So it gives you access to children of headlines if you generated the data with `(org-element-parse-buffer)`.

The section consists of the text below the headline up to the next headline.

> Assuming that's true, I've tried to org-element-parse-buffer of the whole buffer when I find a top-level headline. With the whole AST, I think I should be able to get the text just under the top-level headline.

The following version of your function shows how you get the bounds of the content with `org-element-map`.

```el
(defun get-headline-with-text ()
  "Return a list with the headline text of the top-level headline for point as first element and the section text as second element."
  (interactive)
  (require 'subr-x) ;; for when-let
  (when-let ((data (org-element-parse-buffer 'greater-elements)) ;; sparse parsing...
         (headline (org-element-map
               data
               'headline
             (lambda (el)
               (let ((beg (org-element-property :begin el))
                 (end (org-element-property :end el)))
                 (and (>= (point) beg)
                  (<= (point) end)
                  el)))
             nil
             'first-match
             'no-recursion))
         (headline-text (org-element-property :raw-value headline))
         (section (org-element-map
              headline
              'section
            #'identity
            nil
            'first-match
            'no-recursion))
         (text-begin (org-element-property :contents-begin section))
         (text-end (org-element-property :contents-end section)))
    (list headline-text (buffer-substring text-begin text-end))))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put `require` outside of the function body?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 It depends since `when-let` is a macro. If the stuff goes into an initialization file like `~/.emacs` the current implementation is best. Initialization files should not be compiled. Thus `subr-x` can be loaded right before the usage of `when-let`. If the stuff goes into a byte-compiled library it is best to put `(require 'subr-x)` outside the function wrapped into `eval-when-compile` since the macro is (only) needed at compile time.

Comment: `eval-when-compile` works in interpreted scripts as well, so code might be written in such a way that it could be moved into a utility library and compiled when needed.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 The motivation for putting the `require` into the function body is that we probably do not need to load `subr-x.elc` at all if we never call `get-headline-with-text`.

Comment: The output of the function is clearer if you use `buffer-substring-no-properties` insead of `buffer-substring`. Then `(car (cdr (get-headline-with-text)))` gets the text.

Answer (score 2):

> First, does org-map-entries just not allow me to access children of
>   headlines? (I think the text description is in a section that's a
>   child of the first headline. Right?)

TBH I'm not sure, but you can use `org-element-map` to save the position of each top-level headline. Once you have the position, go to it and move the point to the next heading. Everything between points a and b is what you need.

```el
(defun get-headline-with-text ()
  (let (hl1
        (hls (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
                 'headline #'identity)))
    (dolist (hl hls)
      (when (= (org-element-property :level hl) 1)
        (push (org-element-property :begin hl) hl1)))
    (setq hl1
          (cl-loop for hl in hl1
                   for beg = (save-excursion
                               (goto-char hl)
                               (point))
                   for end = (save-excursion
                               (goto-char hl)
                               (outline-next-visible-heading 1)
                               (point))
                   for result = (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)
                   collect result))
    (nreverse hl1)))
```

---

Update

The function above parses *all* top-level headlines in the buffer, which is not what the question asks. Here's another attempt:

```el
(defun get-headline-with-text ()
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (ignore-errors (outline-up-heading 1))
      (let* ((elt (org-element-at-point))
             (title (org-element-property :title elt))
             (beg (progn (org-end-of-meta-data t) (point)))
             (end (progn (outline-next-visible-heading 1) (point))))
        (list title (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))))))
```